# How to dynamically give the collection filed name in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I have these codes now:

```
OneCollection.find({}, {fields: {'oneFiled.child1': 1}});
OneCollection.find({}, {fields: {'oneFiled.child2': 1}});
```

But I want to give a dynamically child filed name.

```
let childfield = "child1";
OneCollection.find({}, {fields: {'oneFiled.childfield': 1}});  // How to write this one?
```

How can I dynamically give the filed name? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this ?

```
let childField = 'child1';
let listFields = {};
listFields['oneField.'+childField]=1;
OneCollection.find({}, {fields: listFields });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)** to construct the field object as follows:

```
var childfield = "child1",
    options = { fields: {} };

options["field"]["oneField."+childfield] = 1;
OneCollection.find({}, options);
```

Comment: @HongboMiao Thank you for noticing :)

Comment: thanks, @chridam, both yours and apaz's ways work perfect!